# What linux distribution for programming and hacking?

Tags: linux, operating-system, system

can some one tell me what linux distribution is better. Linux mint or Kali linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this question doesn't belong here, but I will try to answer it. Almost every distribution is suitable for programming, since you can install all the tools you want in every distro. Pick a distro you are comfortable with.

If you are just starting out and are unfamiliar with linux, I suggest trying out Ubuntu or Mint. I don't have any experience with Kali linux, but according to the wikipedia article it is aimed at digital forensics and includes wireshark, nmap and other network tools. Again, these are tools you can install in every linux distro.

Comment: But for example when I try to install ghost phisher on my mint it says that the package is broken, and I think is because kali linux is based on debian and mint is based on ubuntu :/ I'm not sure.

Comment: Mint is based on Ubuntu, but Ubuntu is based on debian so that shouldn't matter. Programs can run on multiple distro's, as long as you have the correct dependencies installed. I don't know how you try to install it, but maybe follow the instructions at https://code.google.com/p/ghost-phisher/. It provides a list of dependencies, a .deb download (package for debian based systems) and an option to download the code from svn.